# The basis of $U^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $U^*$ a linear transformation from a $n$ dimension vector space to a $m$ dimension vector space. Are the basis of $U^*$ $u_{pq} = (a_{ij})$, where $a_{ij} = 1$ if $i = p$ and $j = q$, $a_{ij} = 0$ otherwise? To expand this, the basis would look like

$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots \\
 0& 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots \\
 0& 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix},
\cdots,
\begin{pmatrix} 0&0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots \\
 0& 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}.$

And therefore, for all $m \times n$ dimension matrices is a linear combination of these basis.

Answer (score 1):

This would imply that there is only one linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ - and that is definitely not the case!

Comment: Hi I guess I didn't make it clear. Please kindly see my edit and see if it make sense now. Thanks!

Comment: I had an abuse of notation. When I said $u_{mn}$ I actually meant $u_{pq}$ - I corrected. Is it right now? Thank you.

Comment: Then this is a basis for the set of ALL linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ - it is an abuse to say that it is the basis of some specific transformation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a unique basis. Any minimal spanning set forms a basis. For example, the vectors $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ form a basis for the plane, for all $\theta$.

The standard basis for vector space of linear transformations - usually identified with a set of matrices - is the basis consisting of matrices with a 1 on a single place and then a 0 everywhere else. For example, if we have a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ then we get three-by-two matrices. A basis looks like
$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right], \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right],\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right],\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right],\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right],\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Thanks - I guess I meant exactly what you said. Could you please see my question and see if it is correct? Thanks!

Comment: More or less. I think you should say that the basis is $u_{pq} = (a_{ij})$ where $a_{ij}=1$ if $i=p$ and $j=q$, or $a_{ij}=0$ otherwise. You have $m$ and $n$ as fixed number, the dimension of the range and domain. So $u_{mn}$ is a fixed element.

Comment: And what are you in your present life... You used your power for good? (if you are confused by this phrase, you may refer to the question with most votes...)

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, I meant $pq$. Just an abuse of notation - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a basis of $\hom(V,W)$, the vector space of linear maps from $V$ to $W$. It *can* be interpreted as a basis when you fix a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of $V$ and a basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ of $W$ and consider the linear maps
$f_{ij}$ ($1\le i\le m$, $1\le j\le n$) defined by
$$
f_{ij}(v_k)=
\begin{cases}
w_i & \text{if $k=j$},\\
0 & \text{if $k\ne j$},
\end{cases}
\qquad (k=1,2,\dots,n).
$$
We use the fact that a linear map is completely determined by defining its action on a basis of the domain.

It can be proved that $\{f_{ij}:1\le i\le m, 1\le j\le n\}$ is a basis of $\hom(V,W)$. The matrix associated to $f_{ij}$ with respect to the chosen bases of $V$ and $W$ is indeed the matrix that has $1$ as $(i,j)$-entry and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that an **ordered basis** $\left\lbrace v_1, v_2,...,  v_n \right\rbrace $of a vector space $V$ is a linearly independent set such that any element $v$ of the vector space can be written as a unique linear combination of elements of the basis, that is
$$ v = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i$$
for some scalars $\alpha_i$. Any ordered basis is, of course, a basis, and the cardinality of such any basis is unique (although basis are usually not unique) and it is called the **dimension** of $V$. The space of linear transformations between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ (this space is sometimes denoted $\mathcal{L}\left( V, W \right)$ and it can be easily shown to be a vector space itself).

If $U^* \in \mathcal{L}\left( V, W \right)$ where $\dim\left(V\right)=n$ and $\dim\left(W\right)=m$, then $U^*$ can be written as a linear combination of the matrices you are considering. To show this, let $\left\lbrace v_1, v_2, ..., v_n \right\rbrace$ be an ordered basis for $V$ and $\left\lbrace w_1, w_2, ..., w_m \right\rbrace$ be an ordered basis for $W$, then for each $j=1,2,..,n$ the image of the vector $v_j$ by $U^*$ is uniquely written as
$$ U^*\left(v_j^*\right) = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{ij} w_i $$
for some scalars $\alpha_i$. So the matrix
$$  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 
\alpha_{11} & \alpha_{12} & ... & \alpha_{1n} \\
\alpha_{21} & \alpha_{22} & ... & \alpha_{2n} \\
\vdots  &  & \ddots &   \vdots \\
\alpha_{m1} & \alpha_{m2} & ... & \alpha_{mn} \\
\end{array} \right] $$
is called the **matrix representation of the linear transformation $U^*$** relative to the basis $\beta = \left\lbrace v_1, v_2 , ..., v_n \right\rbrace$ and $\gamma = \left\lbrace w_1, w_2 , ..., w_m \right\rbrace$, it is sometimes denoted $\left[U^* \;\right]_\beta^\gamma$, this matrix contains information of how any vector in $V$ is expressed in terms of a basis of $W$. It is visible that if we denote by $\left(a_{ij}\right)$ the matrix whose entries are all zero except for the entry $\left(i,j\right)$ where it takes the value 1, then
$$ \left[U^*\right]_\beta^\gamma = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij} \left(a_{ij}\right) $$
showing that the matrix representation of $U^*$ is a linear combination of the matrices $\left(a_{ij} \right)$.

Note that even though the matrix representation of $U^*$ depends on the choice of the bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$, it is always true that *any* matrix representation of $U^*$ can be written in terms of the matrices $(a_{ij})$. This almost shows that such matrices form indeed a basis for $\mathcal{L}\left( V, W \right)$, the problem is that we are mixing matrices and transformations. One solution is to identify $\mathcal{L}\left( V, W \right)$ to the space of matrix representations of transformations between $V$ and $W$ written in terms of some fixed bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$, this would be sufficient to show that the matrices $(a_{ij})$ form indeed a basis.

Another solution is to consider the linear transformations $T_{ij}$ as the unique linear functions such that $T_{ij}(v_j)=w_i$ and $T_{ij}(v_k)=0$ for $k\neq i$ (recall a linear transformation is completely determined by its values on some basis). If this is the case, each matrix $(a_{ij})$ is the matrix representation to relative to $\beta$ and $\gamma$ of the function $T_{ij}$ and clearly we have
$$T\left(x\right) = \sum_i \sum_j \alpha_{ij} T_{ij}(x)$$
for each $x \in V$, and so $T = \sum_i \sum_j \alpha_{ij} T_{ij}$, showing that the functions $T_{ij}$ form a basis for $\mathcal{L}\left( V, W \right)$.

Going back to your question, unless I am am missing the concept of a basis of a transformation, then I believe you wanted to ask about the the basis of the vector space of transformations. Also note that your definition of the matrices $\left(a_{ij}\right)$ defines only one matrix, which makes less sense to me.

Comment: I had not seen your edit before, but I believe this should answer it.

Comment: I had an abuse of notation. When I said $u_{mn}$ I actually meant $u_{pq}$ Thank you.

Comment: Is $L(V,W)$ means $\text{Hom}(V,W)$? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, Hom $(V,M)$ denotes the **morphisms** between the objects $V$ and *W*, but a morphism in the context of vector spaces is simply a linear transformation. I will also slightly edit my answer to make it more formal.